# using regex in python to return line and some lines are skipped

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am new to Python and programming in general. My code gets data from a pdf. Then iterates over the returned lines to pull only lines meeting a regex expression. Most lines have data in the next line that need to be added to the current line which is being iterated over. The code I wrote does this successfully except that lines that do not have data in the next line to be added, returns the current line but skips the very next line.

What can I add or change to make sure that it does not skip the line.

An example of the lines that need to be iterated over are:

```
#Input text

CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT 1,664.58 0320 2,130.05
MUTUAL/IBS /GAL /0000010318908
IB TRANSFER TO 2,000.00- 0323 130.05
578441575425   10H32 28662338
FEE-INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFER ## 5.50- 0323 124.55
8419752
IB PAYMENT FROM 9,000.00 0325 9,124.55
JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE
IB PAYMENT FROM 1,000.00 0401 10,124.55
JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE
MONTHLY MANAGEMENT FEE ## 21.00- 0331 10,103.55 (This line has no description in the following line)
CREDIT TRANSFER 9,000.00 0401 19,103.55 (This line gets skipped)
ABSA BANK rent
IB TRANSFER TO 19,000.00- 0403 103.55
578441575425   11H45 286623383

bpdf = 'test pdf.pdf'

with pdfplumber.open(bpdf) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)

new_trn_line = re.compile(r'(\D+)(\d.*) (\d.*) (\d.*\.\d{2})')

def transactions(sentences):
    for lines in sentences.split('\n'):
        yield lines

my_list = transactions(text)

my_data = []

for each_line in my_list:
    if new_trn_line.search(each_line):
        my_next_line = next(my_list)
        if not new_trn_line.search(my_next_line):
            my_data.append(new_trn_line.search(each_line).group(1) + my_next_line + " " +
            new_trn_line.search(each_line).group(2) + " " + new_trn_line.search(each_line).group(3))

    elif re.search(new_trn_line,text):
            my_data.append(each_line)
    else:
        continue

my_data
#Output
['CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT MUTUAL/IBS /GAL /0000010318908 1,664.58 0320',
'IB TRANSFER TO 578441575425   10H32 286623383 2,000.00- 0323',
'FEE-INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFER ## 8419752 5.50- 0323',
'IB PAYMENT FROM JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE 9,000.00 0325',
'IB PAYMENT FROM JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE 1,000.00 0401',
'MONTHLY MANAGEMENT FEE ## 21.00- 0331 10,103.55',
'IB TRANSFER TO 578441575425   11H45 286623383 19,000.00- 0403'\]
```

If you compare it to the input you will see CREDIT TRANSFER 9,000.00 0401 19,103.55 gets skipped

Comment: Can you please create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your input text is not line separated, you also don't need pdfplumber for MRE. Otherwise it is not fun for users to help you. Nevertheless, my question would be if the double-backslashes are necessary!? The rawstring will interpret this as non-escaping characters, resulting in `\\\\\`.

Comment: Apologies colidyre, when I pasted the code it automatically added an extra backslash to all backslashes. and I did not notice it. I also corrected the input text.  I hope this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current pattern would not match `(\D+)(\d.*) (\d.*) (\d.\*.\d{2})` as `\*` matches an asterix which is not in the example data.

If you have read the whole text from the `.pdf`, perhaps you could use a single pattern with capture groups, and assemble the results.

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\d\n]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ chars other than digits or newlines
- `(\d[\d,.-]* \d+)` Capture **group 2** Match a digit followed by optional repetitions of digits, comma's, dots or a hyphen. Then match a space and 1+ digits
- `\d[\d,.]*\.\d{2}` match a digit followed by digits, comma's and dots and then match `.` followed by 2 digits
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\n(?!.*\b\d[\d,.]*\.\d{2}$)` Assert that the line does not end on a digit with a decimal part having a dot and 2 digits
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` close the non capture group and optionally repeat to also match just a single previous line
- `)` Close group 3

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cmOQHD/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^([^\d\n]+)(\d[\d,.-]* \d+) \d[\d,.]*\.\d{2}((?:\n(?!.*\b\d[\d,.]*\.\d{2}$).*)*)"
my_data = []
text = ("CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT 1,664.58 0320 2,130.05\n"
            "MUTUAL/IBS /GAL /0000010318908\n"
            "IB TRANSFER TO 2,000.00- 0323 130.05\n"
            "578441575425   10H32 28662338\n"
            "FEE-INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFER ## 5.50- 0323 124.55\n"
            "8419752\n"
            "IB PAYMENT FROM 9,000.00 0325 9,124.55\n"
            "JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE\n"
            "IB PAYMENT FROM 1,000.00 0401 10,124.55\n"
            "JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE\n"
            "MONTHLY MANAGEMENT FEE ## 21.00- 0331 10,103.55\n"
            "CREDIT TRANSFER 9,000.00 0401 19,103.55\n"
            "ABSA BANK rent\n"
            "IB TRANSFER TO 19,000.00- 0403 103.55\n"
            "578441575425   11H45 286623383")

matches = re.finditer(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)

for _, match in enumerate(matches):
    my_data.append(f"{match.group(1)}{match.group(3).strip()} {match.group(2)}")

print(my_data)
```

Note sure why in your example output only `MONTHLY MANAGEMENT FEE` ends with `10,103.55` because all the other output lines seems to end with 4 digits.

Output

```
[
'CATS THIRD PARTY PAYMENT MUTUAL/IBS /GAL /0000010318908 1,664.58 0320',
'IB TRANSFER TO 578441575425   10H32 28662338 2,000.00- 0323',
'FEE-INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFER ## 8419752 5.50- 0323',
'IB PAYMENT FROM JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE 9,000.00 0325',
'IB PAYMENT FROM JENNIFER LIVINGSTONE 1,000.00 0401',
'MONTHLY MANAGEMENT FEE ##  21.00- 0331',
'CREDIT TRANSFER ABSA BANK rent 9,000.00 0401',
'IB TRANSFER TO 578441575425   11H45 286623383 19,000.00- 0403'
]
```

Comment: Thank you. The backslash in '(\d.\*.\d{2})' should not net be there is should be '(\D+)(\d.*) (\d.*) (\d.*\.\d{2})' . I have corrected the post

Comment: @StefS Did the answer work out for you?

Comment: yes it did thank you. The only issue I now have is that in the pdf after the sample text there is some general lines that it is now including in the last transaction line. But I think I found a way around it.